EPICS Extending motor record
I'm trying to insert the new field to the Motor record in EPICS.
For this, I perform the following steps:

In the constructor in MyMotor/MyMotorApp/src/MyController.cpp,

MyController::MyController(const char *portName, const char *IOPortName, int numAxes, double period) : asynMotorController(portName, numAxes, ... ) { 

}


I've added the following string:
createParam("NEWFIELD", asynParamInt32, &m_newField_);

In the class description in MyMotor/MyMotorApp/src/MyController.h
I've added the class member
int m_newField_
class MyController: public asynMotorController {
public:
    MyController(const char *portName, const char *IOPortName, int numAxes, double period);

private:
    int m_newField_;
};

The code was successfully  compiled by the command mingw32-make.
However, as I have tried to start the create IOC-program, the new field "NEWFIELD" was not available. What can be the reason?
